# error when using RadioGroup in android

Tags: java, android, radio-group

I'm using RadioGroup in android when I came across this error, 
and I am unable to find out why:

```
Process: com.example.vinicius.crudnotas, PID: 16753
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
```

code below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inserir_notas);
    Button botao = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Controller crud = new Controller(getBaseContext());
            EditText nota1Id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
            EditText nota2Id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            String nota1String = nota1Id.getText().toString();
            String nota2String = nota2Id.getText().toString();
            double nota1 = Double.parseDouble(nota1String);
            double nota2 = Double.parseDouble(nota2String);
            double notaFinal  = (nota1+nota2)/2;
            String resultado;
            String escolha;
            RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_materia);
            int op = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            if(op==R.id.radio_php) {
                escolha = "php";
            }else if(op==R.id.radio_java) {
                escolha = "java";
            }else {
                escolha = "Escolha uma opcao";
            }
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = escolha;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
```

}
}

I need to get the text of the selected RadioGroup to enter the bank

Answer (score 0):

The error is that `nota1String` or `nota2String` does not contain any valid `Double` value or its string representation. Since these are user input fields, just make sure you handle cases where the user does not put any values there. Here are some small changes I think you can make in your `onClick` function:

```
try{
   String nota1String = nota1Id.getText().toString();
   String nota2String = nota2Id.getText().toString();
   //here I check if the string is empty, and then put "0" instead.
   double nota1 = Double.parseDouble((!nota1String.trim().isEmpty()?   nota1String: "0"));
   //again, here I check if the string is empty, and then put "0" instead.
   double nota2 = Double.parseDouble((!nota2String.trim().isEmpty()? nota2String: "0"));
   double notaFinal  = (nota1+nota2)/2;
}
catch(Exception e){
   //something went wrong above...
}
```

Comment: Cool, if this works for you, you can accept the answer so that your question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inserir_notas);
    Button botao = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Controller crud = new Controller(getBaseContext());
            EditText nota1Id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
            EditText nota2Id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            String nota1String = nota1Id.getText().equals("")?"0":nota1Id.getText().toString();
            String nota2String = nota2Id.getText().equals("")?"0":nota2Id.getText().toString();
            double nota1 = Double.parseDouble(nota1String);
            double nota2 = Double.parseDouble(nota2String);
            double notaFinal  = (nota1+nota2)/2;
            String resultado;
            String escolha;
            RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_materia);
            int op = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            if(op==R.id.radio_php) {
                escolha = "php";
            }else if(op==R.id.radio_java) {
                escolha = "java";
            }else {
                escolha = "Escolha uma opcao";
            }
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = escolha;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
}
}
```

Hope it will help you :)